Error código álgebra lineal
Disculpad porque soy nuevísima en R, así que lo siento si no me explico del todo bien. Estoy haciendo una práctica de álgebra lineal (análisis de componentes principales, en la que me proporcionan imágenes de 40 personas de 46x56 pixeles. Lo primero que te piden es guardarlas en formato array con el siguiente código:
library ( OpenImageR )
setwd ( image _ directory )
Files <- list . files ()
Results <- list ()
for (i in seq _ along ( Files )){
Image <- readImage ( Files [i])
Results [[i]] <- Image
}
X = array (as. numeric ( unlist ( Results )), dim =c(N, R, C))introducir el código aquí

Creo que hasta aquí he sido capaz de hacerlo. Luego te piden representarlas como vectores para poder operar con ellas, con el siguiente código:
library ( ramify )
X_ vector = resize (X, nrow =N, ncol =M, byrow = TRUE )
X_ matrix = resize (X_vector , N, C, R, byrow = False )

Aquí viene el primer atasco, no sé exactamente en qué línea tengo que añadir el nº de filas y columnas. He probado varias combinaciones pero no soy capaz de ejecutarlo correctamente.
Espero que no sea una pregunta tontísima, pero creo que por no hacerlo bien en ese punto, los siguientes ejercicios no me están saliendo bien.
Gracias!
